# Android Studio R is error

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

How can I fix the R. problem in android studio.

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
```

Here an error is occurring and it's showing that R can't resolve

Comment: `Rebuild/Clean` your project.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, Android Studio cannot build R file because of an error in a resource file, like an unclosed xml tag. It can be any kind of xml file. Check your xml files which you edit last, menu_game for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue inyour .xml, post it if you cannot identify the issue. Then do a clean/rebuild project. R will be regenerated if your layout is correct.